# Email address change on careers site, then verify link goes to "Page Not Found"

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I changed my email address on Stack Overflow Careers, received the verification link, but when I clicked it, the page was a 404.

[image]

The link generated was https://stackoverflow.com/uk/jobs/email/verify/114310/sGtIpg?usertype=jobseeker

Comment: Can you e-mail into careers@stackoverflow.com with the e-mail addresses you were using and what you're currently using?